# Is there any way to comment/uncomment the VM arguments in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

[image: Run Configuration from Eclipse]

For example, Here I just want to comment this whenever I do not need this argument. I don't want to erase this. So, Is there any way to comment/uncomment the VM arguments in eclipse?

Comment: Duplicate the Run Configuration and make the changes in the duplicate.

Comment: surrounding it in double quotes may work and remove the dash

Comment: @greg-449 you mean create a Run Configuration without these argument instead of erasing? If that is what you mean, I am looking for something like commenting feature.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. There is no commenting feature

Comment: @JorgeCampos Tried with the way you said. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not believe there is a way to do that.

However, for `-D` options you could use the following work-around:

> change `-Dlog4j.debug=true` to `-DXXlog4j.debug=true` or similar

A system property whose name is not recognized by anything should simply be ignored.

<sup>(Hypothetically, an application *could* iterate all of the properties and do something with them all ... beyond simply printing / displaying them.  But that is pretty contrived / perverse.)</sup>

Unfortunately this approach won't work for other options.  In general, unrecognized JVM command line options will cause errors.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I used to comment the following way (won`t be printed during runtime):

```
-Dcomment=<comment>
```

Here, `<comment>` can be anything, but do not use spaces. Use dot (.) instead. For example:

```
-Dcomment=this.is.my.comment
```

This works in Eclipse as well as in IntelliJ VM arguments.

Comment: I think the asker means is there anyway to comment out the VM arguments so that they aren't parsed when you start the JVM.